# What's the best function to switch rows and columns in a table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I’m running a compliance project that has work we need to do (WorkToDo column) mapped to each law that requires we do it (Law#1, Law#2, Law#3):

[image]

I’d like to generate a pivot table that maps that shows each law mapped to the work required by it:
[image]

What’s the best way to do this?

Comment: With Office 365 this can be done with FILTER()

Comment: I might be misunderstanding (sorry if so), but I don't want to filter out any data. I just want to represent it differently as shown above.

Comment: Filter the `WorkToDo` for where it shows `Yes` in the wanted law-column

Comment: Transpose maybe helpful, but not exactly same as the second picture. Need some others efforts.
Ctrl + C → CTRL+ALT+V → select "Transpose"

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, dynamic for number of columns and rows

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"WorkToDo"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
x = Table.Group(  #"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Attribute"}, {{"Concat", each Text.Combine([WorkToDo],":"), type text}}),
DynamicColumnList  = List.Transform({1 ..List.Max(Table.AddColumn(x,"Custom", each List.Count(Text.PositionOfAny([Concat],{":"},Occurrence.All)))[Custom])+1}, each "Item." & Text.From(_)),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" =  Table.SplitColumn( x, "Concat",  Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), DynamicColumnList)
in #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Power Query

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Close and Load

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please see the steps on the picture. In this way you don't get empty cells in between.

[image]